# Gtk+ 3 in C. Can't cast properly in callback function

Tags: c, gtk, signals

Well, I am basically new in Gtk, I am sending a structure as a parameter to a callback function that will be launched when the user clicks the button. When I try to obtain its values, it does not fill them properly I don't know why.

The Counter data Structure has the following:

```
typedef struct{
  int flag;
  GtkWidget* textview;
  GtkWidget* label;
  gchar* test;

} Counter_data;
```

And my piece of function called is this:

```
static void start_counter(GtkWidget *btn, gpointer data){
  int counter = 59;
  gchar* tiempo;
  g_print("starting/restarting counter\n");
  gtk_button_set_label((GtkButton*)btn, "Started counting");
  while(gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();
  while(1){
    sleep(1);
    tiempo = get_minutes(counter++);
    g_print(tiempo);
    g_print("%d\n",((Counter_data*) data)->flag);
    /* gtk_label_set_text((GtkLabel* )((Counter_data*) data)->label, "testing2"); */
    while(gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();
  }
}
```

In my main process I put this:

```
  Counter_data counter_data;
  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Pomodoro 0.1");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), ((Screen_size *) user_data)->x, ((Screen_size *) user_data)->y );
  parentBox = gtk_box_new(FALSE, 0);
  btn_box = gtk_button_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  textview = gtk_text_view_new();
  label_time = gtk_label_new(NULL);

  counter_data.flag = 0; //we are just starting the counter.
  counter_data.textview = textview;
  counter_data.label = label_time;
  counter_data.test = "testing...";
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(parentBox), btn_box, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(parentBox), textview, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(parentBox), label_time, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

  btn = gtk_button_new_with_label("Start counting");
  g_signal_connect(btn, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(start_counter),&counter_data);
```

When I print in console the value of flag

```
g_print("%d\n",((Counter_data*) data)->flag);
```

It prints garbage or and address, I am not sure anymore. My linter says everything is fine :S

Comment: counter_data is allocated in stack. Are you sure it's still in scope when the button is pressed? If you had a minimal complete test case here I could see for myself but...

Comment: Not the answer (what jku said is probably right), but: your counting thing should either be a thread or a `g_timeout_add()` callback; this will avoid the need to pump events in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, the problem was that I had not allocated space using malloc

```
  Counter_data *counter_data = malloc(sizeof *counter_data);
```

Thanks for your help guys!